# NodeJS - Mongoose Find Duplicates from 2 collections based on multiple fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, duplicates, aggregation-framework

I am new to MongoDB (NoSQL) databases.

I have 2 collections.

Model InvoiceDump:

```
    const InvoiceDump = new Schema({
        InvocieNumber : String,
        InvoiceDate : Date,
        Vendor : String,
        Amount : Number,
        Currency : String
    });
    mongoose.model('InvoiceDump', InvoiceDump);
```

Model CurrentInvoice:

```
    const CurrentInvoice = new Schema({
        InvocieNumber : String,
        InvoiceDate : Date,
        Vendor : String,
        Amount : Number,
        Currency : String
    });
    mongoose.model('CurrentInvoice', CurrentInvoice);
```

Almost all fields are same. I am having a requirement to compare CurrentInvoice with InvoiceDump  and find duplicate records like below.

```
    [
     {
       "CurrentInvNo": "12345",
       "CurrentVendor" "5343",
       "CurrentAmount": 5000,
       "CurrentCurrency": "USD",
       "MatchedDuplicates": [{...}, {...}]
     },
     {},
     {},
     {}
    ]
```

In normal SQL, we can apply join / left join InvoiceDump to CurrentInvoice table and find list of duplicate invoices. I am unable to find how NoSQL query works. Can anyone help ?

Comment: What makes a document a duplicate? all 5 fields must match?

Comment: May be I didnt mentioned that. Pls consider there are more fields. and I want to find duplicate by either 5 fields or even only by 2 fields.

Comment: you should specify these "rules", in the "SQL" join you use the "ON" columns in the join, we need to know these columns before we can provide an answer.